# How to calculate the surface charge density of a conducting plate moving at constant speed in a uniform magnetic Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, hall-effect

I have conducting plate moving at velocity $v = 6.28\cdot10^5\mathrm m/\mathrm s$ through a uniform magnetic Field of $B  = 0.18\mathrm T$. How can I determine the surface charge density?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackExchange! I did not downvote and unfortunately, the downvoter did not explain why. However, for future reference, the likely reasons are either your inclusion of actual numbers or for not using MathJax to format the question originally.

Answer (score 2):

If your conducting plate is horizontal and moving horizontally with a velocity which is perpendicular to a horizontal magnetic field, then a free charge in the plate experiences a vertical magnetic force of qvB. This puts a charge density on each surface producing an opposing force qE.  Use Gauss' law to determine the charge density from E.

Comment: Yes I understand that, thank you. However since the Electric Field is uniform throughout the plate $$ \nabla E = 0 $$ I don't quite see how to calculate the exact amount. (Also am I right in the assumption that all the charge is at the edges parallel to the direction of motion of the plate?)

Comment: Assuming a thin plate of large area, equal and opposite charges will be on the surfaces of the  plate contributing to the E field inside and canceling outside. Put one of your Gaussian surfaces outside.